# Triggering a breakpoint in a function that is not called

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

This is a weird one.  I have a function on a class which has a breakpoint in it, that is being hit even though the rest of the function is not running.  The amount of code it would take to reproduce this is probably impractical to post here, but this is what I'm seeing:

MyClass.h:

```
enum OptionsEnum { OPTION_1, OPTION_2 };

struct OptionsStruct
{
    OptionsEnum options;
    int value;
};

class MyClass
{
private:
    Initialize(...);
    Process(const OptionsStruct&);

    OptionsStruct m_Options { };
}
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

void MyClass::Initialize(...)
{
    ...do some stuff with local variables... //<--Breakpoint here not triggered
    ...do some more stuff...

    Process(m_Options); //<--Breakpoint here is triggered!  How?!

    ...do yet more stuff... //<--Breakpoint here not triggered
}

void MyClass::Process(const OptionsStruct& options)
{
    ...do some other stuff... //<--Breakpoint here not triggered
}
```

I've seen plenty of posts which have the opposite problem where a breakpoint they were expecting to be hit was optimized out and thus never triggered, but I can't think of how the reverse would be possible: for optimization to cause a breakpoint to be hit in the middle of a function which was never called in the first place.

Stepping the code through shows that it never actually enters the `Initialize()` function, but when run with the breakpoints, it triggers it.  To be sure, I even turned off optimizations and let it run, and it still hits that breakpoint.  And only that breakpoint.  I put a breakpoint on every single line of code in the function, and only that one hits.  The breakpoint in `Process()` also doesn't trigger, even though it's called by the very line that did trigger.

The pattern seems to be that only lines which have member variables in them get hit.  And when they do, if you mouse over `m_Options`, all of the fields in the struct are junk (uninitialized) values.

The callstack is not helpful - it just points to `[External Code]` and below that `[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing...]`  The function is private, so I don't know how it's even possible for external code to be calling it.  Is this a bug in the debugger?  Optimization wizardry of some sort?  What could possibly make something like this happen?

Comment: Make sure you compiled you project in DEBUG mode without optimizations. I may only guess that you compiled it as RELEASE or DEBUG but with optimizations and the compiler optimized out some stuff making debug process vary confusing.

Comment: The C++ compiler (clxx.exe) crashes for me when interpreting the `OptionsStruct m_Options { };` line. If I remove the braces, everything works normally and no breakpoints are hit. Weird.

Comment: @AlexLop. We actually do the reverse - it's compiled as RELEASE but without optimizations.  There are other parts of the code which depend on it being in release build.  I could try going back to just DEBUG, but it's about a 20-minute compile (the code base is quite huge) every time you switch modes, so I don't do that very often.

Comment: @AustinMullins - Are you using C++11?  That's not available in C++0x.  It basically just initializes the struct with default values for every field.  Also, I don't expect other people to see the same behavior with just this code.  Our actual code base is quite large and would be impossible to post here in any meaningful way.

Comment: Yes, it's C++11. I can do initializer lists and lambda's in `_tmain` all day long, it was just confused when I tried to use an empty initializer list in the class definition.

Comment: After that breakpoint is hit, can you continue? Does you program appear to execute correctly (aside from breaking at that point)? Can you switch to the assembler and see what is going on there? Stepping over a few of the asm instruction (do you see `ret` there?), do you get into familiar code? When you said "without optimizations" - what exactly did you mean? /Od? On what level? (It can be set individually on every cpp file.)

Comment: Yes, it continues after the breakpoint.  If you step through when the breakpoint is hit, it jumps to a completely different part of the code though, rather than stepping through the function where the breakpoint is.  As far as optimizations, yes, it is the /Od at project level.  Haven't dug into the assembly yet - it's a little hairy due to multi-threading and callbacks, so things don't always run in a straightforward manner...

Answer (score 0):

Memory corruption could cause the problem. Maybe somewhere in your code you have a corrupted pointer and it may be a side-effect of using it.
It would partially explain why you can't acces callstack.
Just to be sure... Is the breakpoint in exactly the same source code that you run? It is possible to debug even if the code differs from the compiled version. It would make breakpoints useless.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the same code.  I've done a full clean/rebuild just to be sure I wasn't getting stale code.

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints in other places in the program in order to localize which part of code triggers the problem? If the problem doesn't exist when you step through the wole execution, maybe the problem is concurrency-related.

Comment: I did put a breakpoint at every callsite where `Initialize()` is called, and none of them are hit before the breakpoint triggers.  Some of them trigger afterwards, but that's expected behavior.  It's just weird this one line in the middle of a function gets hit before any other part of the function or any other function that calls it...

Comment: That's why I'd look for a memory corruption that could be present in a totally different part of code. I was thinking about a scenario, where you try to use a pointer somewhere in the code but the object it pointed was deleted/doesn't exist and now it points on this exact line. The execution could crash in the debud mode, but it is possible, that it works on release.

Comment: It is very likely you corrupted the callstack.  The common way to do that is with a C array declared as a local variable in a function and then written to past its size.  Then when the function in which that variable was declared tries to return, you get a wild jump.  You should understand the function and class reached by the wild jump likely have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Alright, to test this theory, I tried swapping the order of the code a bit, re-ordering the method declarations and definitions, which should have no effect on execution, but would put this code on a different line.  It still triggers erroneously no matter how I reorder the code.  (And the line number it used to be on does not trigger a breakpoint.)  Now of course the compiler might be emitting the same code even when the source is in a different order, but that would be difficult to track...